# Using Matlab writematrix in several scripts to write to the same csv

Tags: matlab, csv, overwrite

To analyse some data I have severral scripts that take the same input and calculate different things. I would like to have matlab then write the output of each script to the same csv so I have all the outputs in one place. How do I do this? Is this even possible w/o making a huge matrix in Matlab and writing the whole matrix in one comaand? As far as I can tell writematrix only ever writes to the first column.

Example:

> A = rand(1,10)'; B = rand(1,10)';
>
> writematrix(A,'M.xls') %write to column 1 of csv
>
> writematrix(B,'M.xls') %this overwrites the previous command

You can write to different sheets in xcel, but that's not suitable.

The documentation for writematrix is here: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writematrix.html

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the range (or the starting cell) for second column using the `'Range'` property and use `'append'` for  `WriteMode` as shown below:

```
A = rand(10,1);    B = rand(10,1);  
%Side-note: ' is complex conjugate transpose. 
%Use transpose .' when you want to take transpose
%In this case, you can initialise the random matrices with 10x1 size 
%instead of 1x10 size and then taking the tranpose

writematrix(A,'M.xls');
%Assuming that B1 is the starting cell for the second column:
writematrix(B,'M.xls','Range','B1', 'WriteMode', 'append');
```